# Double EMA into Single EMA

Tags: power-series, time-series, exponential-sum, telescopic-series

The exponential moving average (EMA) operator is defined as:

$$y_t(x, \lambda) = (1-\lambda) \sum_{i=0}^\infty \lambda^i x_{t-i}$$
where $1-\lambda$ is the normalization factor, and the operator is a convolution filter with unbounded support and strictly $\lambda<1$

A double EMA is application of this operator twice on the input process, $x_t$:

$$y_t(x,\lambda_1, \lambda_2) = (1-\lambda_1)(1-\lambda_2) \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty  \lambda_1^i \lambda_2^j ~x_{t-i-j}$$

Is it possible to express this double summation as a combination of single summations instead, either as a closed form solution or asymptotically under certain conditions?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "combination of single summations" and why you're looking for it - every sum over an enumerable set (such as $\mathbb{N}^2$) can be expressed as a single summation with the iterating variable over an enumeration over that set.

Comment: I'm looking to re-write the double sum as a combination of $\Sigma_1 \lambda_i x_{t-i}$ and $\Sigma_2 \lambda_j x_{t-j}$. As for why i'm looking for this, if I wanted to perform this operation over N $\lambda_1$ values and M $\lambda_2$ values, all possible permutations would require NxM operations using double ema, but it would take N+M operations using a combination of single EMAs. Significantly more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty\lambda_1^i\lambda_2^j a_{i+j}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\sum_{j=0}^k\lambda_1^{k-j}\lambda_2^j=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)a_k,\\c_k(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)=\begin{cases}\frac{\lambda_1^{k+1}-\lambda_2^{k+1}}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2},&\lambda_1\neq\lambda_2\\\hfill(k+1)\lambda^k,\hfill&\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda\end{cases}$$

(thus for $\lambda_1\neq\lambda_2$ we reduce to two single convolutions; the case $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$ is also clear).